# Sed regexp not working, what's my error

Tags: regex, bash, replace, sed

I have infected files with some trojan. I need to clean.

Code like this;

```
/*17da00*/
.
.
.
/*17da00*/
```

I want to change space char start with `/*17da00*/` and end with `/*17da00*/`.

I try to

```
sed -i 's|/*17da00.*\/\*17da00\*\/||g'
```

but not working. What is mistake?
Thanks.

Note: I search and replace multiple files with other match using this.

```
grep -Rle "17da00" * | xargs sed -i 's/<!--17da00.*17da00-->/<!-- -->/'
```

Comment: `I want to change space char start with....` what do you mean? remove the content between the two boundaries or what? can you make a better example, with input and output? your sed line won't work, because you tried to match multilines..

Comment: Don't try to disinfect by hand. Restore from version control or backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this form

```
sed -i '/\/\*17da00\*\//,/\/\*17da00\*\//d' file
```